# xmlCleanupParser() memory loss?

Tags: c, libxml2

as `xmlCleanupParser()` from the very good libxml2 is not thread-safe, my question is (and I have no possibility to check it out), how much Memory (rough number) is lost to `xmlParseFile()` and -more importantly- is this memory loss cumulating over many calls to `xPF()`?

Comment: I for some reasons, cannot use valgrind or other tools

Comment: Can't you lock all other code when making libxml2 calls?

Comment: Just run `xmlParseFile()` in an infinite loop and you'll find out soon enough if there's accumulating memory loss.  Or run it 1000 times or so with delays in between and look at your platform's process viewer to see if memory usage increases over time.

Comment: I've a sneaking suspicion the amount lost is going to be a linear function of the file size, and therefore you likely know the answer better than we (they are, after all, your files).

Comment: @WhozCraig sure? my understanding is, xmlFreeDoc() frees everything Documentrelated and xCP() frees everything internal-Parser-Related?

Comment: @PeterMiehle I'd buy that. The underlying parser engine *may* be holding on to cruft, to be sure. I've not used libxml (I'm a tinyxml guy), but I bet the source is readily available. Have you checked it (ie. Use The Source, Luke) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact, that `malloc()` and `free()` or whatever memory handling implementations are not necessarily thread safe in C < 11, there's always the problem of shared/global memory. File handles to the same file in different threads aren't that bad as long as they're read only.

However, starting with libxml2 2.4.7, you might be able to enable thread safety at the API level, for single threads per document: http://www.xmlsoft.org/threads.html

When I look at the sources of libxml2 2.9.1, I'm positive that thread safety is fully implemented, despite global mutexes, there's also an atomic allocation function.

Downloads:
ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to get that thread-flag under OS/2 to compile the lib and enforce the use of the Init-Function in all parts of my legacy-code.

Answer (score 1):

following the advice given by meaning-matters, and using the only tool, I found under OS2 (this ancient old IBM operating system) to check memory, there seams to be no difference in memory-loss between using xCP() or choosing not to (for me).